# JDBC Postgres stored function call returning setof 'myType'

Tags: function, postgresql, jdbc, callable

I'm trying to protect my database from SQL Injection. I have many stored functions that return SETOF my predefined data types. For example:

```
create type userLoginUserIdPasswordReturnType as
(
  userId integer, -- user.id
  password text 
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "user_login_get_id_password"(usernameIn text)
returns setof userLoginUserIdPasswordReturnType as
$$
declare
    sql text;
begin
      sql =  'select id, cryptpwd from "user" where username = ' || usernameIn ||';';
      return query execute sql;
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

I would now like to call these stored procedures from my Java front-end. From what I've read, using CallableStatement is safer with regards to SQL Injection. This is what I have thus far:

```
public ArrayList<String> userLoginGetIdPassword(String username){
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        try{
            String commandText = "{call user_login_get_id_password(?)}";
            this.cstmt = this.myConnection.prepareCall(commandText);
            this.cstmt.setObject(1, username);
//          this.rs = this.cstmt.execute();
            this.rs = cstmt.executeQuery();
            while (this.rs.next()){
                result.add(this.rs.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("SQL Exception: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

If I try using the execute() method, it asks me to set the ResultSet rs to boolean. If run the way it is (executeQuery()) only the first field (userId) of the returnType can be seen in the ResultSet.

If I call the stored procedure as such:

```
public ArrayList<String> userLoginGetIdPassword(String username){
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        try{
            String query = "select \"user_login_get_id_password\"('" + username + "');";
            System.out.println(query);
            this.stmt = this.myConnection.createStatement();
            this.rs = this.stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (this.rs.next()){
                result.add(this.rs.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("SQL Exception: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I get the correct data.

Also, if there are any further tips to protect my database from SQL Injection, kindly point them out. I've created specific Postgres roles which the application will use, as well as implemented a ConnectionPool (c3p0) to connect to my database - application will be run on a local network. I'm validating user input from different Java Swing components in order to avoid SQL Injection attacks (comment --, semi colon, * and other SQL Commands like DELETE).

Any input would be most welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, PostgreSQL doesn't support the `call` command so that's why your first approach fails.

On the second approach you will have two problems.  The first is SQL injection.  Using the standard binding apprach will fix that.  Your second problem is that you will get difficult to parse data back from your function as you have called it.

A better approach would be something like

```
SELECT * FROM user_login_get_id_password(?)
```

However note that sql injection is possible **inside your function.**   To the extent you can avoid `EXECUTE` that will protect you. If you must use execute, change your query string to:

```
sql =  'select id, cryptpwd from "user" where username = ' || quote_literal(usernameIn);
```

There is no need for a terminating semicolon inside the execute query.  It gets automatically terminated.  You do need to call quote_literal though (use quote_ident() if quoting table/column names).